# java 8 use streams in a "forky" way

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am curious, if it is somehow possible, to not always go just straight within a stream. Imagine this sample code:

```
List<Employee> employees = [...];

employees.stream()
    .map(Employee::getCity)
    .map(City::getCountry)
    .map(countryService::determineHazardLevel)
    .filter(level -> level > 5) // integer
    // this line not possible anymore as I drifted away from my employees ...
    .forEach(employee -> employee.setPriority(HIGH))
```

I iterate over a list of employees and want them to set a priority flag if they live in a city which is in a country with a certain hazard level of 5 or higher.

I'd love to go the stream way as above, but can't find a way to do it. I "am not allowed" to stream my way down the city, country, hazardlevel and possible further, as ultimatively I need my employee object I began with, to set the flag on him.

I only know Java, so I don't even know if this would actually be possible in other, possibly more functional, programming languages.

I could use the following code as a workaround, but it would be nicer to a cleaner way:

```
List<Employee> employees = [...];

employees.stream()
    .forEach(employee -> {
        Optional<Integer> lvl = Optional.of(employee)
            .map(Employee::getCity)
            .map(City::getCountry)
            .map(countryService::determineHazardLevel)
            .filter(level -> level > 5); // integer

        lvl.ifPresent(employee.setPriority(HIGH));
    }
```

Maybe I just got it all just wrong and need to look at it completely different ...

PS: I just wrote this stuff in notepad, not sure if I made some mistakes but I hope the idea comes around. Simply put, I see it like this: Normal streams are commands like `A, B, C, D`. But what I want to do is `A, B, B1, B2, B3, C, D`.
But after going down the B road, I can't go back on my "main stream".

Comment: Going back would require you to recreate the original objects, which you no longer have the information for.  This sounds similar to the question: "why can't a hash be decrypted?"

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution is to chain method calls, just like in [Kayaman’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44159946/2711488).

```
employees.stream()
    .filter( employee -> employee.getCity().getCountry().determineHazardLevel() > 5).
    .forEach(employee -> employee.setPriority(HIGH))
```

Alternatively, you can use the stream steps in an inner operation:

```
employees.stream()
    .filter( employee -> Stream.of(employee)
                               .map(Employee::getCity)
                               .map(City::getCountry)
                               .mapToInt(countryService::determineHazardLevel)
                               .anyMatch(level -> level > 5))
    .forEach(employee -> employee.setPriority(HIGH))
```

But for a simple chain of `map` steps, I’d stay with a chain of ordinary method invocations.

Comment: Well, using an inner stream just for chaining methods... Holger, is that really you? :)

Comment: Hi, Maybe using `Optional` is better in filtering.

Comment: @holi-java: `Optional.map` silently returns an empty `Optional`, if the function returns `null`. You should use it only when such a `null` handling is needed. Besides that, it would require a `filter` step followed by `isPresent`, which is not as concise as a sole `anyMatch`. Also, it doesn’t support handling `int` the same way as `mapToInt`. The latter avoid boxing.

Answer (score 4):

No, as the stream is changing from `Stream<Employee>` to `Stream<Integer>` through the `map()` operations (after all, that's what `map()` is supposed to do, and there's no `unmap()`).

You could only do it with

```
employees.stream().
    filter(e -> e.getCity().getCountry().determineHazardLevel() > 5).
    forEach(...)
```

which is ugly, but keeps the original `Stream<Employee>`. For "less ugly" code, implement `determineHazardLevel()` in `Employee` as well.

Comment: Does `forEach` here mutate the `employees` stream?

Comment: No. Only the (remaining) elements inside it.

Comment: So after calling `.filter(...).forEeach(...)`, does the result include all the employees, or just the employees who live in a hazardous country?

Comment: There is no "result" since the stream isn't `collect()`ed. The original `List<Employee>` contains all the employees, with some having their priority set to high.